# Sufficient conditions for finite-dimensionality?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, big-list

Suppose we are given a subset $A$ of a complex vector space $\mathcal V$, and we are asked to look at the subspace $V$ (Hamel-) spanned by $A$. Of course, a spanning set may be very large compared to the dimension of its span, so my question is: what sort of conditions guarantee that $V$ is finite-dimensional?

Let's say that $A$ isn't something we can muck around with, but that we may make any niceness assumptions on the ambient space that we wish. So, one easy thing we can do is

- if $\mathcal V$ is finite-dimensional, then $V$ is always finite-dimensional.

Something more interesting occurs in normed spaces:

- if $\mathcal V$ is normed, then $V$ is finite-dimensional if its closed unit ball is compact.

(I tried to find a list with Google, and I'd be kind of surprised if nothing like this exists, but I wasn't able to get the search words to find it. So a reference to some compiled list would also be nice.)

---

Context: I am working on a homework question for a Lie theory course. The details of the question don't seem particularly important here, but we construct an action on $C^\infty(G,\Bbb C)$ for each element of $G$, take linear combinations, and are asked to show that this set is finite-dimensional.

Comment: For normed spaces (such as $C^\infty(G, \mathbb C)$ for a compact topological group $G$), compactness of the unit ball is the usual condition for finite dimensionality (Note: although you didn't say so in your question, this is an 'if and only if' statement - finite dimensional normed spaces are characterized as those normed spaces with compact closed unit ball.)  Otherwise, I don't think you'd do better than trying to find a finite subset of $A$ that still spans $V$.

Comment: I guess I didn't make this clear in the question: I'm interested in the answer for my own reasons, certainly. But I also was hoping that, if such a list does not exist, that this could become one. OTOH, if this is really the only game in town (even for better cases like Hilbert spaces, or weirder cases like nuclear spaces) then I guess there is no point?